Installing latest dotnet 8 sdk in debian
We building our own docker container based on the buildpack-deps container. Within our docker file we want to install the latest dotnet sdk version 8.0.302 explicitly via:
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/12/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https dotnet-sdk-8.0=8.0.302*

Unfortunately it only contains the 8.0.301 sdk which is not the latest one. 8.0.302 was released on June 11, 2024. We are getting the following error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package dotnet-sdk-8.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '8.0.302*' for 'dotnet-sdk-8.0' was not found

Running it for 8.0.301 works, but isn't latest.

Reason: they haven't put the 302 in the repo yet. Why not? Dunno, ask Microsoft.

Their own images have been updated, but they don't use the Debian package repository as their source. You can maybe copy their own way of installing it from here

Thanks for the answer, the link to the docker file of there own container helps a lot!
